# XSLT 1.0: how to wrap XML element around other templates?

Tags: java, xslt-1.0

I am using `xsltproc` to process XSLT 1.0 transform on OS X Yosemite; input is HTML, and output is XML.

The idea is that the templates below matching `h1[@class='page-header']` and `div[@class='mixins']` actually work, but the problem is wrapping them in a custom parent XML element (here called `dye`).

I realize my template matching `*` is broken; it's there simply to illustrate the kind of structure I would like to output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|style|script"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="dye">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="h1[@class='page-header']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='mixins']"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="h1[@class='page-header']">
    <xsl:element name="color">
      <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div[@class='mixins']">
    <xsl:element name="tone">
      <xsl:value-of select="p/a[@class='tone']/@href"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for your interest!

Comment: The problem is what?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <dye>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="h1[@class='page-header']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='mixins']"/>
  </dye>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is similar to what I did.  The problem is not that the outer XML element is not being printed.  It is.  The problem is that the selectors are not finding the h1 / div nodes.  Any idea why?

Comment: Please clarify the question, then, and provide sample XML data sent into the transformation.

Comment: I found the solution.  The trick is to prefix the HTML selectors with "//" -- evidently that is a kind of path-prefix wildcard.  Eg:  "//h1[@class='page-header']"